# How to remove data from string builder

Tags: c#, string, stringbuilder

Hi i all having a requirement to delete particular data from a `text` file. I have written some code to get my exact data to remove but now i am little bit confused in removing that particular data can any one help me.

Initially this is my data in `text` file where i am storing to a `Stringbuilder`

```
101 111111111 1111111111110150105A094101                                                      

52201               1                   1         PPD1         111015111015   1111000020000001

6241110000251                00000000011              1                     1 0111000020000001

822000000100111000020000000000000000000000011                                  111000020000001

52251               1                   1         PPD1         011015111015   1111000020000002

6281110000251                00000000011              1                     1 0111000020000002

822500000100111000020000000000010000000000001                                  111000020000002

9000002000001000000020022200004000000000001000000000001
```

Now by using certain code i am getting the data to delete `i.e` assume i would like to delete from `5 to 8` which exists. I am storing this to another `StringBuilder` as follows

```
52251               1                   1         PPD1         011015111015   1111000020000002

6281110000251                00000000011              1                     1 0111000020000002

822500000100111000020000000000010000000000001                                  111000020000002
```

I would like to remove this from the main `Stringbuilder` i am having. Is this the correct process or if any better way let me know

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *could* use `StringBuilder.Replace`.

```
sb1.Replace(sb2.ToString(), "");
```

But better is to iterate over the data you wish to *keep* and serialize it to the file again. Take care to overwrite the file atomically if you don't want to risk losing data if the computer crashes while you are saving.

Comment: I don't want to remove all lines with 5 and 8 i want to remove only that particular data which the user selected

Comment: `@Mark Byers` check my image if user select remove Batch from Batch2 i would like to remove that particular data

Comment: That replacement didn't wrk for me

Comment: Yeah but actually i have to do some more additional code to minus the amounts and all in that file that's why i choose this. If with out any restrictions means i would simply replace that